# Update MySQL field value

Tags: mysql

I am trying to resolve a bug in some existing code

here's the code:

```
$sign = ( $type == 'add' ) ? '+' : '-';

$sql = "UPDATE " . SEARCH_WORD_TABLE . " SET
        word_count = word_count $sign $word_count_change
        WHERE word_id IN ($word_ids);
```

The problem is that the field word_count in the database can contain a value of 0

So if $word_count_change has a value of 1 and it tries to minus that from the word_count 0 then I get an error.

So I changed it to the following:

```
$sql = "UPDATE " . SEARCH_WORD_TABLE . " SET
        word_count = word_count $sign $word_count_change
        WHERE word_id IN ($word_ids)
        AND word_count not like '0'";
```

Whilst the above stopped the error it is not correct as if $word_count_change has a value of 1 and it tries to **add** that to the word_count 0 then it won't update the value.

How can I change it so that it can add $word_count_change if the value of word_count = 0 but
it can't minus $word_count_change if the value of word_count = 0

Hope that the above explains and thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements with placeholder values** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](https://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: `if $word_count_change has a value of 1 and it tries to add that to the word_count 0 then it won't update the value.` What change would you expect in this situation?

Comment: You don't need `$sign`. `x = x + ?` is acceptable as the bound value can be positive or negative. Want to subtract? `$word_count_change *= -1`.

Comment: @Martin if $word_count_change and it tries to add that to the word_count 0 then it won't update which is the issue i'm having. I want it to add the value if word_count is 0 but not minus the value if word_count is 0

Comment: What datatype is word_count

Comment: @RiggsFolly mediumint

Comment: Then why are you using `LIKE '0'` a simple `= 0` would make more sense

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've tried various things - the original code isn't mine just trying to resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you show us the error message. I see no reason why subtracting 1 from 0 should be an issue

Comment: Just use `INT` or `BIGINT`. Fussing around with wacky types like `MEDIUMINT` isn't worth it. The byte "saved" counts for nothing.

Comment: @Riggsfolly - it's only an error as far as the script is concerned as there shouldn't be a minus value in that field so it throws the error and doesn't update. So what i'm trying to do is change it so that if the value of word_count is 0 you can add the value to it but not subtract from it.

Comment: Please dont be coy! Show us the error message. There may be a reason for an error but we cannot know until we know WHAT ERROR we are trying to fix

Comment: @RiggsFolly - appreciate your help and not trying to be coy - the error message is SQL Error : 1690 BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range - but the issue is regardless I don't want a minus value in that field. Just want to add to word_count if the value is 0 but not subtract if the value is 0

Comment: You said MEDIUMINT above in a comment!!!!!!! Now its a `BIGINT UNSIGNED` Well OBVIOUSLY the UNSIGHED BIT WOULD APPEAR TO BE FAIRLY RELEVANT when trying to subtract 1 from zero

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't know that much about MySQL that's what i'm asking for help on some older code that i'm looking at  - MediumInt is what it said in phpmyadmin. For the purposes of what this table is used for then having a negative figure is not what we want - it has to be 0 or above so i'm trying to prevent that.

Comment: Think what an Unsigned Integer might mean. Change that to  INT or signed int and your -1 issue is gone. Surely thats not rocket science

Comment: @RiggsFolly - thanks very much but can I confirm that you mean change the type of word_count to INT - say in phpmyadmin? It's live and don't want to mess it up.

Comment: Just remove the UNSIGNED

Comment: You can also use the GREATEST function, ie word_count = GREATEST(word_count $sign $word_count_change, 0). This will avoid setting the value to anything less than zero.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks very much - all working now as intended and apologies as I was looking at it the wrong way.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments and assistance - appreciated - this is now resolved after @RiggsFolly's comments.